# How to show error messages in forms in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework, ionic3

Here i have try to display error messages in `forms` in `Ionic-3`.

Here is my `email.html` file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="signIn()">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                 <ion-item>
                    <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email</ion-label>
                    <ion-input [formControl]="form.controls['email']"></ion-input>
                  </ion-item>

                  <p *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors && form.controls.email.dirty" class="danger" padding>Email is not valid.</p>

            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

    <ion-list padding>
        <ion-item>
            <button ion-button default item-end color="light" (click)="cancel()">CANCEL</button>
            <button ion-button default item-end color="next" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="next()">NEXT</button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

In my `email.ts` file i have:

```
export class EmailSignupPage {

   form : FormGroup;

   constructor(
       private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
       public navCtrl: NavController,
       public navParams: NavParams,
   ) {
       this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]
       });
   }

   ionViewDidLoad() {

   }

   next() {
       this.navCtrl.push(CredentialPage);
   }

   cancel() {
       this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
   }
}
```

I think my code is fine in `email.ts` file, but i don't know how to display errors in my form when it validate as i'm new to ionic and angular!

Is there any one who can help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (putting conditional red colours, showing conditional messages, other custom behaviours...) ? I mean that you already have a conditional error message that should appear in case there are errors (you use `*ngIf` properly).

Comment: That's the point! I don't know how to use *ngIf to display the error message. What I had to do here is not workings! I will already do the error condition for colors. Can you know how to use *ngIf  in my this case?

Comment: 1) your `signIn()` method ( `<form (submit)="signIn()">` ) will be called when clicking either `CANCEL` button or `NEXT` button, unless you put them outside the `<form>` tag (like moving the whole `<ion-list>...</ion-list>` after `</form>`). 2) You are using the [Angular2 `*ngIf` directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) properly. In fact, `*ngIf="myVar"` works like a javascript `if (myVar){}`. If `myVar` is undefined or is false, `*ngIf` will **not** show the content it is attached to. Take a look at the examples in the link.  (PS: your code behaves well when I build).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have fixed this problem with `*ngIf` condition.

I have set below code and it's working for me:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="signIn()">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                 <ion-item>
                    <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email</ion-label>
                    <ion-input [formControl]="form.controls['email']"></ion-input>
                  </ion-item>

                  <p *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors && form.controls['email'].dirty" class="danger" padding>Email is not valid.</p>

            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

    <ion-list padding>
        <ion-item>
            <button ion-button default item-end color="light" (click)="cancel()">CANCEL</button>
            <button ion-button default item-end color="next" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="next()">NEXT</button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

I need to use only:

```
<p *ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors && form.controls['email'].dirty" class="danger" padding>Email is not valid.</p>
```

Instead of

```
<p *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors && form.controls.email.dirty" class="danger" padding>Email is not valid.</p>
```

Which is showing simply errors if there is!

@JMM thanks for the best answer and you are genius! I need only this `*ngIf="form.controls['email'].errors && form.controls['email'].dirty"`

Thanks you all!

Comment: Thank you. Btw can you write your ionic configuration (the output of `$ ionic version` and `$ ionic config get`->`type:` ). Because `*ngIf` with either `form.controls['email'].errors` or `form.controls.email.errors` work on a ionic `3.7.0` `ionic-angular` app and that's how it should be on other versions. But I wonder maybe there is an ionic (or an angular 2) release with an issue. It would be an issue worth being known if there is one

Answer (score 10):

> I don't know how to display errors in my form when it validates

If you just want to display errors in some places, the `*ngIf` directive is what you will want. Put error messages everywhere you want and add a `*ngIf` to indicate in which cases the message should be shown.

The basic idea with `<p *ngIf="emailIsCorrect">error message: incorrect email</p>` is to have a property in your class (in the .ts file) that you will update to reflect whether or not the message should appear. The main idea is to use methods in your ts file that will perform the checks/validation and update that `emailIsCorrect` property.

As an example, you could use a `(keypress)="performCheckOnKeyPress($event.keyCode)"` attribute in your `<ion-input ...>` to call a validation method when the user presses a key.

See below for more explanations.

### Performing custom checks and validation

> I tried to display error messages in `forms` in `Ionic-3`.

There several choices:

**Showing content/error messages conditionally**:
The [Angular2 `*ngIf` directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) will hide things based on the state of the variables in your .ts file.

`*ngIf` works like a javascript `if`: `*ngIf="myVar"` <=> `if (myVar){}`. An undefined or false `myVar` will **not** show the content. Take a look at the examples in the doc for use cases.

**Performing custom validation**: you might choose to add extra *properties* and *methods* to your class in the .ts file  and display content conditionally using `*ngIf`.

You can also use javascript checks to:

- disable choices (as it is done in your code with `<button [disabled]=""...>`)
- set content like text or CSS classes using **ternary** checks `{{variable ? 'basic-class':'error-class' }}`. You can also use method calls like `<p>{{ foo() }}</p>`, where `foo(){ return "some text"; }`.
- perform custom checks when certain events happen, using attributes on tags (like you would do with the javascript `onclick` => `(click)=""` , `onkeypress` => `(keypress)=""`, ...).
- if you store all the error messages in a single variable and want to show them in one place like `<span>Please correct the following fields **email** and **password**</span>` (when both email and password field do not pass validation), you might use `<span>{{ errorMessagesVariable }}</span>`.
- you might also want to take a look at the angular2 [`ngModel` directive](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) and the examples provided in the doc. In fact, there is a basic validation for email and other components when you use `<form [formGroup] ...>` and the `formGroup` will automatically update fields of the variable `form: FormGroup;` you declared in your .ts file.

The aforementioned elements might not reflect best practices for some use cases. They are mentioned for your own knowledge of the ionic framework.

**Examples**:
For instance, the following ternary is good practice in ionic development:

```
<ion-label color="{{ form.controls.email.errors && form.controls.email.dirty ? 'danger' : 'primary' }}" floating> Email </ion-label>
```

Processing keypress events:

```
<ion-input [formControl]="form.controls['email']" (keypress)="performCheckOnKeyPress($event.keyCode)"></ion-input>.
```

### Error in your code

**HTML issue**:

There is an error in your code that makes it get sent whether or not it is valid.

When you put a `<button>` in a form, when pressed that button will trigger the form submission method you provided for the form (`<form (submit)="signIn()" ...>`). In this case, pressing the `CANCEL` button *will also submit the form*.

**the fix**: if you want to have the CANCEL and NEXT buttons next to each other, you might prefer moving both of them outside the `<form>...</form>`  tag.
Note that by moving the NEXT button outside the form, it will not submit the form anymore (it will only call your `next()` method).

If you want your NEXT button to submit the form even outside the `<form>`, you shall also call your `signIn()` method when it is clicked. i.e. `(click)="next(); signIn()"`.

Note: you can write pretty much plain javascript for the `(click)="..."` and other angular directive attributes (works also for `*ngIf="..."`). There are some limitations to that javascript though, but just try the JS code you would love to put there...

---

### Note for ionic v1 developers

Ionic 1 used angular 1. Ionic v2/v3 use angular 2.
Changes introduced in angular 2:

- `(keypress)=""`, `(click)=""` replaced `ng-keypress=""` and `ng-click=""`.
- `*ngIf`, `*ngFor` replaced `ng-if` and `ng-for`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Very good answer for the newbie in Ionic! I have do all things right in my `.ts` file, just don't know how to display it. Here you have tried to explain everything which is good for me and other newbie for Ionic. Thanks man! Cheers! :)