# Angular 6 and Ionic 3 reactive form validation error not display

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am working on a project which uses the latest version of Angular and Ionic. I am working on a registration page. I need to display some error when the form input is not valid. I am using Angular Reactive form in my project but if I check error on the page it is not displayed. It only shows red color underline but I need to show some readable errors

[image]

Here is my View code

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list class="items-middle" text-center>
    <!-- use the [formGroup] directive to tell Angular that we want to use the registrationForm as the "FormGroup" for this form: -->
    <form [formGroup]="registrationForm">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Full Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="userName"></ion-input>
        <div *ngIf="!registrationForm.controls['userName'].valid && registrationForm.controls['userName'].touched"> name is required</div>
      </ion-item>
      <!-- <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="ligh-grey" floating>Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="ligh-grey" floating>Date of Birth</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="dob"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="ligh-grey" floating>Phone Number</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="number" formControlName="phone" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="ligh-grey" floating>Address</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="address"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="job_status">
                <ion-label color="ligh-grey" floating>Job Status (Position)</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" formControlName="jobStatus"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Job Sector</ion-label>
                <ion-select formControlName="jobSectore">
                    <ion-option value="f">Government</ion-option>
                    <ion-option value="m">Private</ion-option>
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isTosRead"> -->
      <!-- We can check if our form is valid: -->
      <ion-buttons padding-top>
        <button ion-button full round type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">SIGNUP</button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </form>
    <pre> {{registrationForm.status}}</pre>
    <pre> {{registrationForm.value | json }}</pre>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And this is my TS file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-registration',
  templateUrl: 'registration.html',
})
export class RegistrationPage {

  registrationForm: FormGroup;
  userName: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // this.registrationForm = new FormGroup({
    //   userName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')]),
    //   email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.minLength(4)]),
    //   dob: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]),
    //   phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(10)]),
    //   address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(255)]),
    //   jobStatus: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]),
    //   jobSectore: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    //   isTosRead: new FormControl(false, [Validators.requiredTrue])
    // })

    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      'userName': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$'), Validators.required])]
    });
  }
}
```

What exactly is the wrong here? Why am I not getting the `*ngIf` condition, console doesn't show me any error.

Comment: I think you have cover both condition in single one like
*ngIf="!(registrationForm.controls['userName'].valid && registrationForm.controls['userName'].touched)"

Comment: so you mean i need to check them separately?

Comment: currently if you submit is it not showing not required?

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal since you had `touched` on the field with `&&` condition, you have to touch the field to see error.

Comment: `registrationForm.get('userName')` should return the formControl to you

Comment: i have touched it, even i remove that condition i cannot see my div error

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera i changed what you mention above here and after i got error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegistrationPage.html:14)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the condition as follows,

```
this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: [
        null, Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$'), Validators.required])
      ],
```

**EDIT**

Also change your template as follows,

```
<ion-item *ngIf="!registrationForm .controls.userName.valid && (registrationForm .controls.userName.dirty)"> <p>Please enter a valid name.</p> </ion-item>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and kind consideration sir, but it show me the same output, no any text based visual error. :(

Comment: oh! just try with this <ion-item *ngIf="!registrationForm .controls.userName.valid  && (registrationForm .controls.userName.dirty)">
            <p>Please enter a valid name.</p>
          </ion-item>

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal modified the answer, you can get from the 2nd answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363533/how-to-show-error-messages-in-forms-in-ionic-3

Comment: i haven't this line "!registrationForm.controls.userName.valid" controls and control object name :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan what was the need of adding `Validators.maxLength(30)`?

Comment: @PankajParkar that was just a sample. no need in this case

Comment: waited for modification, now it is completed. :) and you mention answer post 2nd answer said different story, he escape object name, opposite what we did here. i am so confuse. look carefully about 2nd answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363533/how-to-show-error-messages-in-forms-in-ionic-3

Comment: @PankajParkar it is optional you know what that mean right ;)

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal i linked the answer to know what you actually missed in the template not to see the implementation

Comment: @Sajeetharan I was comparing OP code and your suggestion. I don't see any difference now. Am I missing something? what's the problem with `touched`? You used `dirty`

Comment: hmm but my question is still open, i tried 2nd answer way but it is not worked

Comment: brother the 2nd part of the condition show me error in VS code like "[Angular] Identifier userName is not defined" that will affect to me?

Comment: @PankajParkar yeah you are right! the only difference here is i have used dot operation instead of OPs way. using touched would still work

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal have you defined in the component?

Comment: I think i got the my wrong here, i put div tag inside the <ion-item> tag, that is the wrong i think.

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal yeah that is another mistake here. you should use condition on ion item instead

Comment: those who wonder different between .get vs .controls read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642926/formgroup-get-vs-formgroup-controls-in-reactive-form-angular/49643393#49643393

Comment: @Sajeetharan hey, using dot operation, and accessing object by key, both are same. There is no difference these two ways :\

Comment: @PankajParkar yes there is no difference and both ways are working

Answer (score 1):

Add `<span>` tag with your formControl like this :

OR Add `class="text-danger"` in your current `<div>`.

**.html** file.

**Display `required` Error Message**

```
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['userName'].hasError('required') && (registrationForm.controls['userName'].dirty || registrationForm.controls['userName'].touched)">Field is required</span>
```

**Display `pattern` Error Message**

```
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['userName'].hasError('pattern') && (registrationForm.controls['userName'].dirty || registrationForm.controls['userName'].touched)">Enter valid username.</span>
```

**ts** file.

```
this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
  'userName': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$'), Validators.required])]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and kind consideration sir, but it result is same

Comment: Use `p` tag instead of `span` tag.

Comment: no brother here is problem i have not set control object name like this =>  "!registrationForm.controls.userName.valid" now it is working

Comment: Okk that's great.

Comment: `!registrationForm.controls.userName.valid` is really works. But if you want to display different different error message than try my given answer. Ex. In your case. You have two validation for same Control. Like `pattern` and `required`. You can use like `hasError('pattern')` and `hasError('required')`.

Comment: could you give me some example what you taking about sir? :)

Comment: What you do if you want to display different different message for 'pattern' and 'required'?

Comment: pattern error, here i used pattern  Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$') i have no idea about hasError method and hasError('pattern') sir

Comment: okay and hasError('pattern') method will trigger when user not followed pattern which we set in our ts file? i mean i mention this patter  Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$') and when your not follow this pattern i can check that using hasError('pattern') this method right? :)

Comment: And your in-build logic here is pretty cool, because it give error when touched, and required and pattern miss match situations. and you set nice error like "enter a valid name" pretty smart. i have break it into 2 just check pattern in another div, but you know what i think your logic is fine and meaning full for every situations

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the error message `div` outside the `ion-item` tag like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list class="items-middle" text-center>
    <form [formGroup]="registrationForm">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Full Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="userName"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngIf="registrationForm.get('userName').touched && registrationForm.get('userName').invalid"> name is required</div>
      <ion-buttons padding-top>
        <button ion-button full round type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">SIGNUP</button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </form>
    <pre> {{registrationForm.status}}</pre>
    <pre> {{registrationForm.value | json }}</pre>
    <pre> {{registrationForm.get('userName').invalid | json }}</pre>
    <pre> {{registrationForm.get('userName').touched | json }}</pre>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Also, you can simply use `registrationForm.get('userName').touched && registrationForm.get('userName').invalid">`

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6a8fpq?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html).

Comment: Thank you your code also worked to me sir, my wrong is put div tag inside the <ion-item> tag?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. And I'd use `registrationForm.get('userName')` instead of using `registrationForm.controls['userName']`.

Comment: Sir, any special of .get() method?

Comment: You might want to read this for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49643393/2622292

Comment: help a lot sir.