# Angular Form validation not showing on Angular form error

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

This is my HTML

```
 <form [formGroup]="applicationDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="appDetails(applicationDetailsForm.value)">
    <label>Organization Name</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="appName" id="appName" required>
      <p class="error_message" *ngIf="
      applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').hasError('required') 
      && applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').touched 
      && applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').minLength 
      && applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').maxLength">Provide a valid name</p>
```

and this is my component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.applicationDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      appName: new FormControl ('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32), 
        Validators.minLength(4)]))
})
```

The errors in the Forms are not showing up.
Please help!

Comment: where is your submit button? please post full code related to the form.

Comment: There's a lot of `&&`s in that condition.  Does the error message appear if you comment some of those out?

Comment: refer this link, may this help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52354740/8358892

Answer (score 1):

You're testing for `minLength && maxLength` in your condition to display the error message.  They'll never both be active at the same time.

You're also not looking for the `minLength` & `maxLength` errors correctly. 
 They're not a direct property of the `FormControl` itself—they're `errors` subproperties.

You might have better luck with this:

```
*ngIf="
    applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').touched && (
        applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').hasError('required') 
        || applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').hasError('minLength')
        || applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').hasError('maxLength')
    )
"
```

Consider also adopting the [Angular best practices](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators) of accessing the `FormControl` through a getter:

- `component.ts`:

  ```
  get appName() { return this.applicationDetailsForm.get('appName'); }
  ```
- `component.html`:

  ```
  <form [formGroup]="applicationDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="appDetails(applicationDetailsForm.value)">
      <label>Organization Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="appName" id="appName" required>
        <p class="error_message" *ngIf="appName.touched && (
            appName.errors.required
            || appName.errors.minLength
            || appName.errors.maxLength
        )">Provide a valid name</p>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Validators.pattern`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.applicationDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      appName: new FormControl ('', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9]{4,32}$')]))
})
```

> html

```
<form [formGroup]="applicationDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="appDetails(applicationDetailsForm.value)">
    <label>Organization Name</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="appName" id="appName" required>
      <p class="error_message" *ngIf="
      applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').hasError('required') && applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').hasError('pattern') 
      >Provide a valid name</p>
```

this way you will have more control over the validation.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can add separate error messages for every validation error.

```
<p class="error_message" *ngIf=" applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').hasError('required')">Name is required</p>

<p class="error_message" *ngIf=" applicationDetailsForm.get('appName').minLength">Name length should not be less than 4 charactors</p>
```

As you have `&&` between your validations in the template the condition is always **false**. The min length and max length will not be true at the same time.

Comment: `minLength` won't work because you aren't looking for it in the correct place.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52379218/4877269).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write so much to get the reference to the input field. Try displaying the error messages like this.

```
 <form [formGroup]="applicationDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="appDetails(applicationDetailsForm.value)">
    <label>Organization Name</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="appName" id="appName" required>
      <div *ngIf="appName.invalid && (appName.dirty || appName.touched)">
        <p *ngIf="appName.errors.minlength">
          Name must be at least 4 characters long.
         </p>
        <p *ngIf="appName.errors.maxlength">
          Name must not be more than 10 characters long.
         </p>
       </div>
  </form>
```

**in .ts file**

```
// create a getter for the form control
get appName() { return this.applicationDetailsForm.get('appName'); }
```

Comment: This won't work, because `appName` is not exposed as a `FormControl` by the component in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.applicationDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    appName: [{value: '', disabled: false}, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32), Validators.minLength(4)]]
  })
}
```

template:

```
<p class="error_message" *ngIf="
      applicationDetailsForm['controls'].appName.hasError('required') 
      || applicationDetailsForm['controls'].appName.touched 
      || applicationDetailsForm['controls'].appName.hasError('minLength') 
      || applicationDetailsForm['controls'].appName.hasError('maxLength')">Provide a valid name
</p>
```